# Is there a nice Java object to hold a 2D grid of doubles?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, datagrid, double

Is there a data type that simply holds a 2D grid of doubles?

Preferably in the JDK but I'm happy to use an open source 3rd party library like apache commons etc.

I'm looking for a class, and/or complimentary helper classes, that allow methods like these:

```
Grid g = new DoubleGrid(100, 100);

double min = g.getMinValue();
double someCell = g.getValueAt(x, y);
double origin = g.getValueAt(Coordinate.ORIGIN);
```

Ideally, more complicated things like:

```
Grid newGrid = GridTransformer.transform(g, new CellValueSquarer());
```

I'm completely making these classes up, and I don't need those particular methods per se, It's just an example of the *sort* of thing I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/), which is a linear algebra package (and thus contains a matrix which is a 2D grid of doubles), or [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/), which contains lots of mathematically useful stuff, including linear algebra.  [EJML](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/), which @pablochan mentioned, is another reasonable choice.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a simple 2-dimensional array?

```
double[][] pixels = new double[100][100];
double mine = pixels[12][65];
```

Wrap it in some simple class as desired.

*But there may be existing implementations somewhere...*

Comment: I was a bit vague with "Nice java object" but basically, I _could_ write my own but I was looking for something off-the-shelf since it is more likely to be faster and full-featured than anything I write...

Comment: What about double min = pixels.getMinValue(); ?
mattburns question was quite precise and had a concrete use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [EJML](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/) or just google 'java matrix library'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [javax.vecmath](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/package-frame.html)